# SPD 2007 Custom Calendar NewForm.aspx broke DispForm.aspx

Tags: custom-form, list-view, list, sharepoint-designer

Hello I edited NewForm.aspx in a Calendar List now every time someone clicks on an event in any calendar view for the list, it takes the user to NewForm.aspx instead of DispForm.aspx, I changed GUIDs in both pages, and everything is correct in Properties / Supporting Files via SPD, but I can't get it to work. When you switch views to All Items and click an event it takes you to DispForm.aspx correctly so I know it works, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What changes did you make to NewForm.aspx? Obviously it's best practice to never touch the OOTB NewForm, EditForm and DispForm files. It's far better for you to copy the contents into a new file, modify that file, then change the list properties to point to the appropriate file.

My suggestion would be to do that; ie: copy the source of your modified files to new files, then reset the definition on the original files--this will reset them to their OOTB configuration. Then edit the list properties to point to your modified ones. My assumption here is that once you do that it "may" tweak itself back to life.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a new list and exporting the original data and pasting it in